Seeking cookie cutting instructions
I'm used to MapInfo so are there basic QGIS instructions on how to use one shape to cut a shape out of another shape in a vector layer?
I realise it's not referred to as cookie-cutting in QGIS.
I don't code, nor do I want to watch a 15 minute youtube video, just a couple of sentences explaining how to do it would be great.
I am using QGIS 3.34.
